# iPad doesn't ask me anymore for the app to open Airdropped PDFs with

Tags: ios, ipad, airdrop

Until recently, PDF files Airdropped to my iPad worked and I was asked which app to open the file with, but no more. Now Airdrops “succeed” but I’m not asked which app to open the PDF with, and sometimes I can't even find the Airdropped file. This works fine on my iPhone. I am running iOS 13.6.1.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have the same issue. It opens random apps for it. Did you find how to fix??